# AEM Sightly: passing variables to JSP templates

Tags: jsp, aem, sightly

In Sightly, I need to call a JSP template, but pass it some variables. Like this:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<sly data-sly-include="${ 'test.jsp' @ title='1' }" data-sly-unwrap></sly>
```

So in my JSP I'd want to do this:

```
<%@attribute name="title" %>
<p>title: ${title}</p>
```

However that doesn't work. "title" doesn't get defined.

Do I need to do something special in my JSP or Sightly file?

Comment: include plugin does not process arguments. so you can't pass values to jsp. better create a component instead of standalone jsp and use `data-sly-use`

Answer (score 0):

This will not help you right now, but we're actually planning to add support for request attributes in [SLING-5812](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-5812).

It will definitely be available in AEM 6.3 but technically you can start experimenting with it as soon as we release version 1.0.20 of the Apache Sling Scripting Sightly Engine.